# PHP Zero integer is being evaluated as false

Tags: php

As the title says, PHP seems to be evaluating the integer value 0 as false.

Take for example this snippet:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13d885fb68359a3154999c2ef85db7c913c49bc5

```
<?php

if($exists = checkDup()){
    echo $exits;
}
else{
    echo "error!";  
}

function checkDup ($foo = 'blah', $bar = 'blah'){
    if ($foo == $bar) return (int) 0;
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, despite casting the reply as an int PHP parsing the return as false which in incorrect.

Comment: Because that's what it is flagged as.. return it as "0"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is evaluating a lot to false ;)
For example null, '', 0
You have to include a type check as well, you can do so by using `===` or `!==`

```
$exists = checkDup();
if($exists !== false){
    echo $exits;
}
else{
    echo "error!";  
}

function checkDup ($foo = 'blah', $bar = 'blah'){
    if ($foo == $bar) return 0;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `if($exists = checkDup() !== false)`

`0 == false; //true`

`0 === false; //false`

When you don't specify the a boolean expression in the `if`, it will execute the `==` operator